# Unregistering panels in python

Tags: add-on

I found out that I can remove panels via python with these command:

```
bpy.utils.unregister_class(bpy.types.SCENE_PT_physics)
bpy.utils.unregister_class(bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add)
...
```

Ican then customize my interface with an addon. My problem is that I get an error if the panel is already unregistrered. Is there a way to check before unreg? like so:

```
if bpy.types.SCENE_PT_physics not None:
   bpy.utils.unregister_class(bpy.types.SCENE_PT_physics)
```

EDIT (after reply):

Ok so I try do it as posted by Duarte Farrajota Ramos. But would like to automate it so I don't have to write in a console - like this:

```
import bpy

all_classes = (
bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_snapping,
)

for single_class in all_classes:
    module = single_class.__module__

    from module.name import single_class

    if module.single_class.is_registered:
    #Do stuff
```

This doesn't work and I'm not sure how to handle pythons types. That is I'm confused when I have a string of the name of the module or when I have the object it self and what I'm supposed to use when importing several variable modules ect.

Comment: hasattr(bpy.types, "SCENE_PT_physics")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Import the class def**

If a type is in `bpy.types.FOO` it implies it is registered.

Wouldn't recommend unregistering using

```
bpy.utils.unregister_class(bpy.types.FOO)
```

particularly if you wish to re-register it, as unregistering it removes it from `bpy.types`.

Rather, would recommend importing them. If you are not sure where the classes are defined,  turn on developer extras and view source or check the classes module property

```
>>> bpy.types.SCENE_PT_physics.__module__
'bl_ui.properties_scene'
```

Hence can import it, check if it is registered by looking at its `is_registered` property

```
>>> from bl_ui.properties_scene import SCENE_PT_physics
>>> SCENE_PT_physics.is_registered
True

>>> bpy.utils.unregister_class(SCENE_PT_physics)
```

and then re-register if need be to "uncustomize"

```
>>> SCENE_PT_physics.is_registered
False

>>> bpy.utils.register_class(SCENE_PT_physics)
```

Note, since most Blender UI code sticks to the convention of putting registerable classes in a list named `classes` can use this, or the modules register methods.

```
>>> from bl_ui.properties_scene import classes
>>> classes
(<class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_UL_keying_set_paths'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_scene'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_unit'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_physics'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_keying_sets'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_keying_set_paths'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_keyframing_settings'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_audio'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_rigid_body_world'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_rigid_body_world_settings'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_rigid_body_cache'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_rigid_body_field_weights'>, <class 'bl_ui.properties_scene.SCENE_PT_custom_props'>)
```

Note.

The module `bl_ui` is blenders UI written in python. The classes listed above are all the UI elements listed in `bl_ui.properties_scene` *ie* the PROPERTIES area in SCENE tab.

The idea here is to not use the class from `bpy.types` rather import it from its appropriate UI submodule.

Hence in your addon code would

```
from bl_ui.properties_scene import SCENE_PT_physics
```

As an example, to take out all panels in the Scene Properties

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel

import bl_ui
# all panels in PROPERTIES > SCENE
scene_prop_panels = [cls for cls in bl_ui.properties_scene.classes
        if issubclass(cls, Panel)]
    
def register():
    # unregister default scene props panels
    for cls in scene_prop_panels:
        if cls.is_registered:
            bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

def unregister():
    # unregister default scene props panels
    for cls in scene_prop_panels.reversed():
        if not cls.is_registered:
            bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks very useful. I asked this in a previous question this day, but is there a way to execute these commands from a seperate module when the addon is loaded? I guess its best not to put them in the __init.py__ file

Comment: EDIT added after seeing *attemptus horriblus*  in question code. Please in future if having trouble Post Your Code, and we can see where you are going astray and help.   Similarly here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202854/installing-my-own-addon  and   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202854/installing-my-own-addon  Also see links posted yesterday https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202854/installing-my-own-addon?noredirect=1#comment340851_202854 re calling the register of other modules from `__init__.py`