# Toggle Panel on/off without unregistering class

Tags: python

I'm trying to add a boolean to my addon preferences menu that when toggled will remove the selected panel. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this without registering/unregistering which doesn't work once unregistered. Any ideas?

```
    if bpy.context.scene.hideCryptoBool == True:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(bpy.types.DARROW_PT_cryptoPanel)

    if bpy.context.scene.hideCryptoBool == False:
        bpy.utils.register_class(bpy.types.DARROW_PT_cryptoPanel)

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Test `bpy.context.scene.hideCryptoBool` in the panel's `poll`?

Comment: Re registering class see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202889/unregistering-panels-in-python  and import  `DARROW_PT_cryptoPanel` from module where it is defined.

Comment: could you explain what exactly poll is, and how its useful?