# Blender api redraw UI

Tags: add-on

I write my Blender addon. And I need to redraw the panel and all panels below it in one of operator `execute`. So I can write

```
def redraw_panel():
    try:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(PanelClass1)
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(PanelClass2)
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(PanelClass3)
    except:
        pass

    bpy.utils.register_class(PanelClass1)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PanelClass2)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PanelClass3)
```

But so I have problems adding new panels below (I need to write **register** and **unregister** for them in above function).

Is there any other way in Blender api to redraw UI and panels in Blender?

Comment: Suggest checking on `if PanelClass1.is_registered:` https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/202896/15543    Above pretty much depends on all being in sync.   A tag redraw _eg_ `context.area.tag_redraw()` is a common way to tag  UI for redraw, although it is often not necessary https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/182852/15543  Assume  you made some changes to panel class definition before calling op above?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Should I write tag ```context.area.tag_redraw()``` in my panel draw method?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it usually @Multifora

Comment: Thanks @brockmann